# C program - Recursion

Tags: arrays, c, function, recursion, combinations

I have a program in which the field has numbers and the players gradually remove either two elements or one from the right or left, the players take turns. I want to count all combinations (player sums). Why do I sometimes get meaningless results here?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int rekurze(int *mince, int start, int last, int playerA, int playerB, int player)
{   
    if (start < last)
    {
        if (player)
        {
            if(last-start == 1)
            {
                rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start], 1);
                rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[last], 1);
            }
            rekurze(mince, start+2, last, playerA+mince[start]+mince[start+1], playerB, 0);
            rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA+mince[start], playerB, 0);
            rekurze(mince, start+1, last-1, playerA+mince[start]+mince[last], playerB, 0);
            rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA+mince[last], playerB, 0);
            rekurze(mince, start, last-2, playerA+mince[last]+mince[last-1], playerB, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            if(last-start == 1)
            {
                rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start], 1);
                rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[last], 1);
            }
            rekurze(mince, start+2, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start]+mince[start+1], 1);
            rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start], 1);
            rekurze(mince, start+1, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[start]+mince[last], 1);
            rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[last], 1);
            rekurze(mince, start, last-2, playerA, playerB+mince[last]+mince[last-1], 1);
        }
    }
    else if(start==last)
    {
        if(player)
            playerA += mince[start];
        else
            playerB += mince[start];
    }
            printf("Skore A: %d, ", playerA);
            printf("Skore B: %d\n", playerB);
}   

int main (void)
{
    int mince[] = {3,5,3};
    int konec = (sizeof(mince)/sizeof(int))-1;
    int start = 0;

    rekurze (mince, start, konec, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the answer, I recommend to get into the habit of using consistent indentation. Actually you did quite strict indentation, even the problematic lines are at an indentation matching the answer. But you did not react on the obvious conflict between that indenation depth and the wrong relation to the nearest `}`. With an ingrained habit that would have stood out to you quite noticeably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are getting meaningless results because your `printf` statements are not in the else if block.
Hence, when `if (start < last)` and `else if(start==last)` is false, you are still printing values in situations that aren't valid in your case.
And if you want to count the unique combinations possible, you can have a look at the edited code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int table[100][100]={0};
int rekurze(int *mince, int start, int last, int playerA, int playerB, int player)
{   
    int ans=0;
    if (start < last)
    {
        if (player)
        {
            if(last-start == 1)
            {
                ans+=rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start], 1);
                ans+=rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[last], 1);
            }
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start+2, last, playerA+mince[start]+mince[start+1], playerB, 0);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA+mince[start], playerB, 0);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start+1, last-1, playerA+mince[start]+mince[last], playerB, 0);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA+mince[last], playerB, 0);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start, last-2, playerA+mince[last]+mince[last-1], playerB, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            if(last-start == 1)
            {
                ans+=rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start], 1);
                ans+=rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[last], 1);
            }
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start+2, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start]+mince[start+1], 1);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start+1, last, playerA, playerB+mince[start], 1);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start+1, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[start]+mince[last], 1);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start, last-1, playerA, playerB+mince[last], 1);
            ans+=rekurze(mince, start, last-2, playerA, playerB+mince[last]+mince[last-1], 1);
        }
        return ans;
    }
    else if(start==last)
    {
        if(player)
            playerA += mince[start];
        else
            playerB += mince[start];
        printf("Skore A: %d, ", playerA);
        printf("Skore B: %d\n\n", playerB);
        if(table[playerA][playerB] == 0)
        {
            table[playerA][playerB] = 1;
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;    
            
    }
    return 0;            
}   

int main (void)
{
    int mince[] = {3,5,3};
    int konec = (sizeof(mince)/sizeof(int))-1;
    int start = 0;

    printf("\nUnique results: %d\n",rekurze (mince, start, konec, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I store the number of unique values ​​in the ans variable and then I store the specific values ​​in the field? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: If I may have one more question? Is it possible to prevent repeated counting of duplicate values?

Comment: @Aaron7 So here, i store the number of values possible in ans variable. And to avoid duplicates, I have used the table[][] array. The table array is 0 at first, and for each value i set it to 1. (you can use a hash data structure for this job as well. Read about it :)   ) Later, i avoid duplicates by checking if that value is 1

Comment: May I still ask how can I find out in which recursion call the highest value of player A was obtained? For what first recursion call. What is the first move a player has to make to achieve a maximum score?

Comment: You can use a global variable to keep track of the highest score obtained so far and add an if condition when the end of recursion has been reached. and to keep track of the first move, add few more parameters to the function to keep track of the first move..